# Increasing understanding of the return keyword when used inside a function

Tags: javascript

I find the use of the return keyword strange to be used twice in this case. Is there any way to refactor this code block so that the return keyword does not need to feature twice like so:

```
  return arr.filter(function (num) {
    return num > 0 && num % parseInt(num) === 0;
```

Here is the overall code block.

```
const squareList = function squareList(arr) {
  return arr.filter(function (num) {
    return num > 0 && num % parseInt(num) === 0;
  }).map(function (num) {
    return Math.pow(num, 2);
  });
};

const squaredIntegers = squareList([-3, 4.8, 5, 3, -3.2]);

console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

Comment: Your code involves three different functions. There's a `return` statement in the `.filter()` callback and a `return` statement in the `.map()` callback. It makes perfect sense as it is.

Comment: Also `Math.floor(num)` would be better than `parseInt(num)`.

Comment: JS allows functions to be defined within other functions.  The `return` keyword exits from its enclosing function only.  If you wish to avoid this, you could move those inner functions outside of the outer function so they're siblings.

Comment: Declaring helper functions in this way is absolute standard. I'd rather suggest getting used to it, than refactoring the code. You can create the helper functions outside, and only use identifiers for them, but it will imho harm readability. In this specific case, you can also use arrow functions' short hand for returns, which will also remove the `return`, and probably even improve readability. However, that is not possible in all situations.

Comment: To elaborate on the last point of the above, an example: `return arr.filter(num => num > 0 && num % parseInt(num) === 0);`